# Devise Password Reset Issue Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication with a Rails 4 app and am having issues with the password reset. Locally, everything works fine, when I paste the reset link in (i.e. localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=e_f3ZpqrE_rTBZmKJk_E) it works as expected.

On Heroku however, Devise seems to not even notice the :reset_password_token param, and automatically redirect to /users/signin with the notice "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided."

Here's is an example of the link that is being generated: http://mysite.io/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=anzYNreZEcz4-dtZy5Uf

I even overrode the assert_reset_token_passed method in my own controller to check if params[:reset_password_token] was actually blank, and for some reason it is, rails is not pulling this out of the url. Here's my modified method:

```
def assert_reset_token_passed
    logger.info params[:reset_password_token] #This is blank somehow
    if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
      set_flash_message(:alert, :no_token)
      redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name) #This is where the redirect happens
    end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the exact same issue. The fix for me was to update the `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in production.rb to include the full host (in my case 'www.mydomain.com' vs 'mydomain.com').

To clarify, it used to be

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }
```

and now it's

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.mydomain.com' }
```

Comment: This was not exactly my scenario but it got me on the right track.  In my case the url generated was http but my app redirects all traffic to https. The redirect loses the query string.

Comment: Brandon, what was the exact fix for you in the end, was it adding :protocol => 'https' - I was hoping this was going to fix it for me, but it hasn't

Comment: Thanks - this addressed this issue for me!

Comment: Adding the full host solved my problem. Thanks for this.